# Converting Integer to Binary and storing values into an array

Tags: c

What I am trying to do is to convert an integer to binary and store these values into an array. What I have done so far is I have created a for loop to get the range of numbers and used an algorithm to convert these to binary. However here are my problems: my program only prints 1 value (0 or 1) on each line when I want each integer to be converted to binary in one line and in the form 0000 0001. Another thing I am struggling with is storing these values into an array.

```
 for(m=0;m<10000;m++)
    {
        const char baseDigits[2]= {'0','1'};
        int convertedNumber[1000];
        int numberToconvert;
        int NextDigit = 0;
        int base = 2;
        int index = 0;
        //get number and base;
        numberToconvert = m;
        //convert to base2
        do
        {
            convertedNumber[index] = numberToconvert % base;
            ++index;
            numberToconvert = numberToconvert / base;

        }
        while(
            numberToconvert != 0
        );

        //display results in reverse order
        for(--index;index>=0;--index)
        {
            NextDigit = convertedNumber[index];
            printf("%c \n", baseDigits[NextDigit]);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove \n from printf with improved for loop as below:

```
index--;
for(;index>=0;--index) {
    NextDigit = convertedNumber[index];
    printf("%c", baseDigits[NextDigit]);//you could have used %d and printed directly convertedNumber[index]
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: You'll probably want to add `printf("\n");` after this code as well.

Comment: Optional but as you say ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer it worked, However I'm still struggling to get this in the format of binary e.g 1 should be 0000 0001

Comment: your could use if to check index value and if its less than 8 then you can pad '0' in loop and then follow your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
for(--index;index>=0;--index)
{
    NextDigit = convertedNumber[index];
    printf("%c", baseDigits[NextDigit]);
    if(index && ++i % 4 == 0)
        printf("%c", ' ');
}
printf("\n");
```